# Прописная буква

Tags: прописная-строчная

Объясните, пожалуйста, с какой буквы нужно писать постановление правительства Нижегородской области (далее название постановления). Везде пишут по-разному: в одном случае - с прописной, в другом - со строчной. А как надо? Спасибо.

Comment: Приведите пример, пожалуйста. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможны оба варианта:

1. Официальное название, официальные документы (это имя собственное): Правительство Нижегородской области. Также: Сведения о полномочиях и обязанностях Правительства. Состав Правительства. Информация о текущей деятельности Правительства.
2. СМИ (неофициальные сообщения, нарицательное существительное): Новая структура правительства Нижегородской области утверждена указом губернатора.

Comment: Вера, лучше ориентироваться на конкретные примеры, тогда и ответ будет точнее. Мы ведь не знаем, что именно написано прописными буквами в тексте.